# REST web service in Rails 3.x

Tags: xml, ruby-on-rails-3, web-services, rest

I have a Rails (3.x) application which I'm trying to communicate with a desktop application (C#.net) via a REST web service api.

I was able to implement all the GET requests and they all are working fine,

Then I have this requirement of POSTing details to my Rails controller. Since I'm developing a restaurant  app my POST method will be something like follows

```
<bill>
  <user_id>1</user_id>
  <table>Table1</table>
  <items>
    <item>
     <name>BEER</name>
     <price>200</price>
    </item>
    <item>
     <name>BREAD</name>
     <price>10</price>
    </item>
  </items>
</bill>
```

As you can see, this `<items> </items>` will be a loop of individual `<item></item>`, elements and there can be 'n' number of `item` elements

My question is, I will be able to create these kind of xml and post it to the Rails controller.

But how could I read the values from the controller?

I guess I could read the header part as

```
user_id = params[:bill][:user_id]
table = params[:bill][:table]
```

But I'm not sure how to read the `<items>` elements. I'm running on Rails 3.x.

Comment: In your logs, what do you see as parameters when you post your request?

Answer (score 0):

I would try to leverage `Nokogiri::XML` and therefore have a ruby-object representation of your xml which then is easily accessible.

```
# your xml lives in params['body']
body = Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse(params['body']) 
body.at("items").children.each do |item|
    #code goes here
end
```

Read about nokogiri and its xml parsing capabilities here: http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet.html